# "JavaMailSenderImpl cannot be resolved to a type" after switching to 4.0.1 Release

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, build

I have developed Spring MVC app with 3.1.1 Framework Version, now I want to switch to 4.0.1.

I am using Maven to handle all the dependencies.So when I change the version in `pom.xml`, I get compilation error `JavaMailSenderImpl` could not be resolved to type.

Also I am not able to locate package `org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl` in the jars.But from docs it looks like this package is not removed in latest version.
I tried cleaning the project & building again but didn't helped me.

So any idea what am I doing wrong here?

[This is the URL to docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSenderImpl.html)

Below is **part** of `pom.xml` -

```
    <properties>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.3.Final</hibernate.version>
        <spring.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.core.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.security.core.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <google-guava.version>12.0</google-guava.version>
        <joda-time.version>2.1</joda-time.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.4</slf4j.version>
        <h2.version>1.3.167</h2.version>
        <jasper.version>4.7.0</jasper.version>
        <commons.digester.version>2.1</commons.digester.version>
        <commons.collections.version>3.2.1</commons.collections.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>     
  <dependencies>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
              <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.core.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Java Mail Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Which artifact contain the said class.I guess context-support contain the class but i dnt found in the POM

Comment: Awesome dude...I was trying to find the artifact which contains said class.And yes context-support contains JavaMailSenderImpl class

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It was dependency, I was missing.So I added following dependency -

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```